# Include table column background colors when exporting to .xls/.pdf

Tags: jquery, html, datatables, export-to-excel, export-to-pdf

I'm using jQuery DataTables to show a table that has multiple cell colors based on employee availability in certain months. I have included 'Buttons' extension of DataTables to it so that the table can be exported to .pdf, .xls formats. However, I am not able to export the table along with all its cell colors. The textual data in the cells are exported perfectly, however the color is not reflected.

Can anyone please suggest a solution for this? I have checked their documentation, but I could not find any mention of an API that permits this to be implemented.

Here's the code that I have written to achieve things along with screen shots of the output

```
//function to load the forecast data into the table in a proper format
window.loadData = function (data) {

    //console.log(data);
    //create the table body rows
    $.each(data, function (i, val) {

        //Append database data here as rows
        var trow = $('<tr></tr>');

        //set the name first
        var tdName = $('<td style="font-size:9pt;white-space: nowrap;">' + val.name + '</td>');

        //append it to the row
        trow.append(tdName);

        //append the forecast columns now
        var tdJan = getTabCol(val, 'jan');
        trow.append(tdJan);
        var tdFeb = getTabCol(val, 'feb');
        trow.append(tdFeb);
        var tdMar = getTabCol(val, 'mar');
        trow.append(tdMar);
        var tdApr = getTabCol(val, 'apr');
        trow.append(tdApr);
        var tdMay = getTabCol(val, 'may');
        trow.append(tdMay);
        var tdJun = getTabCol(val, 'jun');
        trow.append(tdJun);
        var tdJul = getTabCol(val, 'jul');
        trow.append(tdJul);
        var tdAug = getTabCol(val, 'aug');
        trow.append(tdAug);
        var tdSep = getTabCol(val, 'sep');
        trow.append(tdSep);
        var tdOct = getTabCol(val, 'oct');
        trow.append(tdOct);
        var tdNov = getTabCol(val, 'nov');
        trow.append(tdNov);
        var tdDec = getTabCol(val, 'dec');
        trow.append(tdDec);


        //append the row to the table
        $('#tabForecastBody').append(trow);


    });

    //make the table a datatable
    var table = $('#tabForecast').DataTable({

        "paging": true,
        "bLengthChange": true,
        "bFilter": false,
        "lengthMenu": [[6, 15, 25, 30], [6, 15, 25, 30]],
        "language": {
            "emptyTable": "No data to show"
        },
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            //'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
            {
                extend: 'excelHtml5',
                title: 'Resource Allocation'
            },
            {
                extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                title: 'Resource Allocation',
                //text: '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>'
            },
            //{
            //    extend: 'csvHtml5',
            //    title: 'Resource Allocation'
            //},
            //{
            //    extend: 'copyHtml5',
            //    title: 'Resource Allocation'
            //},
            {
                extend: 'print',
                title: 'Resource Allocation',
                //exportOptions: {
                //    columns: [0, 1, 2, 5]
                //}
            }
        ],
        order: [],
        columnDefs: [{ "targets": 0, "orderable": false },
        { "targets": 1, "orderable": false },
        { "targets": 2, "orderable": false },
        { "targets": 3, "orderable": false },
        { "targets": 4, "orderable": false },
        { "targets": 5, "orderable": false },
        { "targets": 6, "orderable": false },
        { "targets": 7, "orderable": false },
        { "targets": 8, "orderable": false },
        { "targets": 9, "orderable": false },
        { "targets": 10, "orderable": false },
        { "targets": 11, "orderable": false },
        { "targets": 12, "orderable": false }]

    });

}

//function to return the value of table column
window.getTabCol = function (val, key) {

    var td = null;

    for (var prop in val) {

        if (prop === key) {

            //now split the prop text based on '^'
            var allData = val[prop].split('^');

            //now create the td
            td = $('<td style = "background-color:' + allData[1] + ';cursor:pointer;color:black;font-size:10pt;text-align:center;" title = "' + allData[0] + '" >' + allData[2] + '</td>');

        }
    }

    //now return the newly created column
    return td;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `getTabCol()`, add the extracted color as attribute to each `<td>` element as well, you can call it `export-color` :

```
...
td = $('<td export-color="'+allData[1]+'" style = "background-color:' + allData[1] + ';cursor:pointer;color:black;font-size:10pt;text-align:center;" title = "' + allData[0] + '" >' + allData[2] + '</td>');
...
```

Now use the `customize` function to extract `export-color` for each cell, and update the cell's pdf `fillColor` with that value :

```
button: [
    { 
        extend : 'pdfHtml5',
        customize: function(doc) {
            for (var r=1;r<doc.content[1].table.body.length;r++) {
                var row = doc.content[1].table.body[r];
                for (c=0;c<row.length;c++) {
                    var exportColor = table
                                        .cell( {row: r-1, column: c} )
                                        .nodes()
                                        .to$()
                                        .attr('export-color');
                    if (exportColor) {
                        row[c].fillColor = exportColor;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    ...
]
```

You can change the text color of each cell as well using

```
row[c].color = 'red';
```

The default styling is a striped effect where each cell have style (a CSS class) as `.tableBodyOdd` and so on. You can reset this or use another class by

```
row[c].style = 'cssClass';
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try this out and will let you know the results. my question now is, does this approach work for exporting to excel also?

Comment: @IamRuku - No, read the description section [**here**](https://datatables.net/reference/button/excelHtml5). dataTables integrates with various open source libraries in order to produce the exports, those libs have different API's and purposes. dataTables does not support detailed customisation when exporting PDF for example, but because pdfmake _itself_ actually supports detailed customisation you are able to do that by clever coding.  Unfortunetaly, the libraries used for exporting to excel does not have such built in capabilities,  and therefore it is not possible.

Comment: ..continued) - I must admit I also fail to see why someone should want HTML styling exported to Excel. The purpose of a PDF is a styled readonly document you can sent as email, print or publish on the web - the purpose of a Excel spreadsheet is to export the data so you can continue work in Excel (I guess).